# Dynamic port and host for Remote-SSH using Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-debugging

I'm using [Remote Develoment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) in VS Code to connect to a Docker-container running on  a server in a cluster. However both the server and the SSH-port gets assigned dynamically, and I can not figure out how to solve this in Remote-SSH.

I know I can edit the SSH-configuration file to specify hosts, ports, users e.t.c. However it's practically impossible to set up this configuration for all possible combination, instead I want to be able to press F1, select "Remote-SSH: Connect to Host" and then type "cleared@hostname -p XYZ". Can this be achieved somehow or is there any other good solution to my problem?